# JSP Form Validation

Tags: javascript, forms, jsp, webforms, jsp-tags

I get stocked in a phrase validation, inside a JSP form. One of the textfields, Called FB-Number, should only accept the format like this : FG123-1238234. (It can be any letters or any numbers)

The number of the digits and letters are not limited and before '-' either digits or letter can come first(FG123-)or(123FG-). In short, before '-' can be only mixture of Capital letters and numbers and after '-' should be only numbers. writing '-'  at the middle is mandatory.

I wrote the following code in the form validation function but it doesn't work. I appreciate if someone can help.

```
    var numericExpression =/^[A-Z0-9]+\-[0-9]\+$/;if(theForm.fb_number.value.match(numericExpression)){
            return true;
    }else{
            alert("Enter valid format for FB_Number");
        theForm.fb_number.focus();
            return false;
    }enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
       String REGEX="[A-Z]{0,}[0-9]{0,}[-]{1}[0-9]{0,}";
       String INPUT ="AB877-53434";

       Pattern p = Pattern.compile(REGEX);

       Matcher m = p.matcher(INPUT);

       System.out.println(m.matches());
         }
}
```

Here u can also chage the occurance of A-Z or 0-9 from 0 to as you desired like {2,}

Comment: The code i have written is part of a WebForm, I think the format could be a bit diferent from what you have suggested.